# No matter where I set the position on the left property, my subform moves all the way left

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have four subforms on a form in access. Sometimes I have no need for one form or the other so I hide them. Well after they are hidden I want to be able to shift the remaining forms over.  I have look all over the internet as far as the Left Property for a subform, and I also tried the move method. I have found almost next to nothing on how to move a subform, at least anything meaningful.

The problem I am having is that no matter what value I specify for the left property or the move method, my subform just moves to the left as far as possible.

```
Private Sub NoPrimerButton_Click()
        Me!PrimerSub.Visible = False
        Me.AddPrimerButton.Visible = True
        Me.AddPrimerButton.SetFocus
        Me.NoPrimerButton.Visible = False
        Me.IntermediateSub.Left = 0.001
End Sub
```

If I set it to Me.IntermediateSub.Left = 2.000 it still moves all the way left.

There is not much out there on this, and I clearly don't understand it so any help would be appreciated. Also These subforms are placed on a Tabular Form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ask me why, but in VBA measurements are in twips (1440 per inch). If you want the subform 2 inches from the left of the main form try:

```
Me!IntermediateSub.Left = 2880
```